# How do I map an Object to carousel slider items?

Tags: flutter, oop

This is the model class.

```
class NewsFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final String categoryName;
  final int liked;
  final String description;

  const NewsFeed({
    Key key,
    @required this.url,
    @required this.categoryName,
    @required this.liked,
    @required this.description,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

This is where I did composition to convert the objects into list

```
class NewsFeedList {
  List<NewsFeed> feedItems;

  NewsFeedList({@required this.feedItems});
}
```

And this is the variable which contains List of NewsFeedItems.

```
NewsFeedList newsFeedList = NewsFeedList(feedItems: [
  NewsFeed(
    url:
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
    categoryName: "CFC Great",
    liked: 200,
    description:
    "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.",
  ),

  NewsFeed(
    url:
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
    categoryName: "HFH Great",
    liked: 200,
    description:
    "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.",
  ),
]
);
```

I couldn't map this List to carousel Items property. Red line appears...
This is the main class where I want to map NewsFeedList

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SportsApp"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
              children: [
              CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(),
          items: newsFeedList              // Error Appears here
          .map((item) =>
          Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Image.network(item,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1200)),
          ))
          .toList(),
    ),]
    ,
    )
    )
    ,
    );
  }
```

The error that comes is:

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.
          .map((item) =>
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of NewsFeed can call by NewsFeedList.feedItems

```
   CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(),
      items: newsFeedList.feedItems.map((item) =>
      Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Image.network(item.url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1200)),
      ))
      .toList(),
```

Also, don't need extends to StatelessWidget

```
class NewsFeed  {
  final String url;
  final String categoryName;
  final int liked;
  final String description;

   NewsFeed({
    @required this.url,
    @required this.categoryName,
    @required this.liked,
    @required this.description,
  }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the class `NewFeedsList` does not have a method called `map`. If the class only exists to hold the list, I would remove it and use a `List` like: `List<NewsFeed> newsList`. Or, you could do something like so:

```dart
class NewsFeedList {
  List<NewsFeed> feedItems;

  NewsFeedList({@required this.feedItems});

  List<Widget> mapToWidget() => feedItems
      .map((item) =>
        Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Image.network(
             item,
             fit: BoxFit.cover, 
             width: 1200,
           ),
         ),
       ),
     )
     .toList();
}
```